# Include coordinates of image pixels transferred from Earth Engine to Numpy array

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am transferring subsets of image pixels from Earth Engine to a client-side Colab notebook as Numpy arrays. How can I know what the latitude and longitude of each pixel is?

Here is a basic example showing how I'm transferring pixels client-side as a Numpy array using [`ee.Image.getDownloadUrl`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-getdownloadurl).

```py
import ee
import io
import numpy as np
import requests


ee.Authenticate()
ee.Initialize()

# A Sentinel-2 surface reflectance image.
img = ee.Image('COPERNICUS/S2_SR/20210109T185751_20210109T185931_T10SEG')

# A small region within the image.
region = ee.Geometry.BBox(-122.0859, 37.0436, -122.0626, 37.0586)

# Image chunk as a NumPy structured array.
url = img.getDownloadUrl({
    'bands': ['B3', 'B8', 'B11'],
    'region': region,
    'scale': 20,
    'format': 'NPY'
})
response = requests.get(url)
data = np.load(io.BytesIO(response.content))
print(data)
print(data.dtype)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add longitude and latitude bands to the primary image. Use the [`ee.Image.pixelLonLat`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-pixellonlat) function to create a lat/lon image and then [`ee.Image.addBands`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-addbands) to attached them to the primary image.

```py
import ee
import io
import numpy as np
import requests


ee.Authenticate()
ee.Initialize()

# A Sentinel-2 surface reflectance image.
img = ee.Image('COPERNICUS/S2_SR/20210109T185751_20210109T185931_T10SEG')

# Longitude and latitude image.
lon_lat = ee.Image.pixelLonLat()

# Add longitude and latitude bands to the primary image.
img = img.addBands(lon_lat)

# A small region within the image.
region = ee.Geometry.BBox(-122.0859, 37.0436, -122.0626, 37.0586)

# Image chunk as a NumPy structured array.
url = img.getDownloadUrl({
    'bands': ['B3', 'B8', 'B11', 'longitude', 'latitude'],
    'region': region,
    'scale': 20,
    'format': 'NPY'
})
response = requests.get(url)
data = np.load(io.BytesIO(response.content))
print(data)
print(data.dtype)
```

[Colab notebook version](https://gist.github.com/jdbcode/558f5c4f1ec40070d55b8bd102f889c2)

If you want projected coordinates instead of lat/lon, use [`ee.Image.pixelCoordinates`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-pixelcoordinates) instead of [`ee.Image.pixelLonLat`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-pixellonlat).